# Laravel default providers are missing

Tags: laravel

Default providers missing after creating new project in laravel,jetstream installed with livewire but RouteServiceProviders and EventServiceProviders are missing

I expected to have all five default Service Providers after creation of new project with jetstream and livewire installations

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/11.x/releases#service-providers - What version of Laravel? If this is Laravel 11 (new release version), there's only one `AppServiceProvider` now.

Comment: It's 11...so where can i get functionality of RouteServiceProvider?

Comment: https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/11.x/bootstrap/app.php for the route files, everything else is part of the framework now. If you want to add API routes take a look at [this](https://laravel.com/docs/11.x/routing#api-routes)

Comment: Alternatively, you can initialize your new project with Laravel 10.x; it'll be supported until February 4th, 2025. I would suggest you go with the new version and follow the documentation, but the choice is ultimately yours.

Comment: Let me stick with the latest one
..thank you.